# Raspberry Pi 4 OBS Virtual camera

Tags: camera, virtual, raspberry-pi4, obs

I wrote this bash file, but not working. I think RPI just 32bit and the package what I found 64bit. Do you have any idea, how to find 32bit version of the package or how can I solve the problem?

I used this repos:
https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback
https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink

This code was the base
https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/obs-raspberry-pi-build-instructions.115739/

```
#!/bin/bash

#########################################################
# delete unnessery programs from pi
#########################################################

sudo apt-get -y remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get -y remove --purge scratch2 minecraft-pi wolfram-engine sonic-pi dillo squeak-vm squeak-plugins-scratch geany
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -y autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

#########################################################
#install obs with virtual camera
#########################################################

#make swap file
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap2 bs=1024 count=1000000
sudo chmod 600 /var/swap2
sudo mkswap /var/swap2
sudo swapon /var/swap2
sudo swapon

#install obs
sudo apt install qtbase5-dev

mkdir -p ~/install
cd ~/install

git clone --recursive https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio.git

sudo apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential checkinstall cmake libmbedtls-dev libasound2-dev libavcodec-dev libavdevice-dev libavfilter-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libjack-jackd2-dev libjansson-dev libluajit-5.1-dev libpulse-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev libspeexdsp-dev libswresample-dev libswscale-dev libudev-dev libv4l-dev libvlc-dev libx11-dev libx11-xcb1 libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-xinput0 libxcb-xinput-dev libxcb-randr0 libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb-xfixes0-dev libx264-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-xinerama0-dev libxcomposite-dev libxinerama-dev pkg-config python3-dev qtbase5-dev libqt5svg5-dev swig
sudo wget http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/fdk-aac/libfdk-aac1_0.1.4-2+b1_armhf.deb
sudo wget http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/fdk-aac/libfdk-aac-dev_0.1.4-2+b1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libfdk-aac1_0.1.4-2+b1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libfdk-aac-dev_0.1.4-2+b1_armhf.deb
sudo git clone --recursive https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio.git
cd obs-studio
sudo mkdir build && cd build
sudo cmake -DUNIX_STRUCTURE=1 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
sudo make -j4
sudo make install

#install virtual cam
cd ~/install
sudo apt-get install -y v4l-utils v4l2loopback-utils
sudo wget http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/v/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dkms_0.12.5-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ~/install/v4l2loopback-dkms_0.12.5-1_all.deb


#install virtual cam obs plugin
cd ~/install
sudo wget https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink/releases/download/0.1.0/obs-v4l2sink.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ~/install/obs-v4l2sink.deb
mkdir -p ~/.config/obs-studio/plugins/v4l2sink/bin/64bit/

#run OBS
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3 obs #only need to run this command from now on
```

Comment: `mkdir -p ~/.config/obs-studio/plugins/v4l2sink/bin/64bit/
ln -s /usr/lib/obs-plugins/v4l2sink.so ~/.config/obs-studio/plugins/v4l2sink/bin/64bit/`

Comment: This working on Ubuntu 20.04 [https://github.com/NapoleonWils0n/cerberus/blob/master/obs-studio/obs-ubuntu.org]

Comment: `06:21:51 PM.684: Failed to load 'en-US' text for module: 'decklink-ouput-ui.so'
06:21:52 PM.186: A DeckLink iterator could not be created. The DeckLink drivers may not be installed
06:21:52 PM.186: No blackmagic support
06:21:52 PM.599: FFMPEG VAAPI supported
06:21:52 PM.713: os_dlopen(/usr//lib/obs-plugins/v4l2sink.so->/usr//lib/obs-plugins/v4l2sink.so): /usr//lib/obs-plugins/v4l2sink.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
06:21:52 PM.713:
06:21:52 PM.713: Module '/usr//lib/obs-plugins/v4l2sink.so' not loaded`